# Serialize UUID's with Marshmallow SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

How can I make `marshmallow` with `flask-marshmallow` to serialize Postgres' UUID column types?

This is the example model, note the UUID dialect of Postgres:

```
import uuid
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@postgres/author_db')
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()


class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "authors"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = Column(String)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Now, the Marsmallow's Model Schema is straightforward, directly from the [example](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#generate-marshmallow-schemas):

```
from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema

class AuthorSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
```

All serialization fails:

```
author = Author(name="Chuck Paluhniuk")
author_schema = AuthorSchema()
session.add(author)
session.commit()
dump_data = author_schema.dump(author).data
```

This will return:

> TypeError: Object of type UUID is not JSON serializable

What is best way to parse UUID's as strings?

One way is to include a `post_dump` to the Model Schema:

```
@post_dump()
def __post_dump(self, data):
    data['id'] = str(data['id'])
```

But I prefer a more general approach to UUID's, because I use a lot of them.

Comment: uuid objects are not serializable, you should convert to str before saving it.

Comment: Use marshmallow's [UUID field type](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/marshmallow/fields.html) for your `Author.id` in the schema. It will serialize to a string. The UUID class inherits from the simple String Field, which serializes by casting with `str()`. Keep in mind, though, it will fail if the `as_uuid` arg is not used in the column spec.